# how to pass variable to cmd that used by subprocess.call

Tags: python, python-3.x

we are using python3 on our Linux machines

I am trying to pass the variable `IP` , in cmd

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, os, logging
import subprocess


IP = '127.0.0.1'


COMMAND = "ping -c 3 IP"
subprocess.call(COMMAND, shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(COMMAND,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True).stdout.read()
```

since we get the error about `ping: unknown host IP`

I am thinking how to pass the IP variable , so later I can execute the cmd with `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.Popen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of providing `COMMAND` as a string, it's safer to provide it as a list instead and leave `shell` at its default value of `False`. That way, you don't have to perform shell escaping in case any arguments contain "special" characters like spaces:

```
COMMAND = ["ping", "-c", "3"]
subprocess.call(COMMAND + [IP])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert the contents of `IP` into `COMMAND`. Here, you can simply add the strings like this:

`COMMAND = "ping -c 3 " + IP`

Comment: For someone whose username and avatar refer to [_that_](https://xkcd.com/327/) xkcd comic, this is a particularly evil answer ;) My IP address happens to be `1.1.1.1; rm -rf /`.

Comment: I'd be lying if I said I didn't have that exact same thought when typing that answer out.